# How to display text and image in bootstrap 4 so the text is inline with the image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to position my elements using bootstrap classes and CSS, but I am failing to succeed.

Currently I have the following html :

```
<div class="container book-wrapper">
  <div class="row">

     <div class="container book-box">
        <div class="row row-one">
           <div class="col-md-">

           <img src="{{$upload->imgURL}}">
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-">

           <h2 id="book-title">{{$upload->name}}</h2>
           <span id="book-desc">{{$upload->description}}</span>

     </div>
  </div>
```

And CSS :

```
    .book-box{

    margin-top:20px !important;
    margin-left:20px;

}


#book-desc {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
    text-align: justify !important;
    text-justify: inter-word !important;

}
```

The output is looking like this :

[image]

Can anybody help me get this right? I just want the text and the title to be displayed in the right and not below the picture.

Comment: use col-md-6 for boh

Comment: Use float and clearfix styles.

Comment: If you want the image to be displayed inline it will be treated as a *letter*, making its row have a much higher line height than the rest. Are you sure that's what you want and not simply floating the image to the left and adding a bit of right and bottom margin to it?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu No, I am not sure. I don't really know what is best to be done here..

Comment: So you expect us to know what you want better than you. Anyway, what you are asking for ***does not need any class***, because, by default `<img>` tags are displayed inline. Why would you want to *"use Bootstrap classes"* to achieve something that's achievable without adding any class?

Comment: Incence, please note your question does not currently contain a clear problem statement and therefore is not technically answerable. People might start guessing what your problem is, but that should not be necessary. It is you who should provide all the details so nobody would have to guess what you want. You show how the output looks (which we can see by ourselves) but you do not define how you want it to look.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I have stated what I want in the bottom : "I just want the text and the title to be displayed in the right and not below the picture."

Comment: Just add `float-left` class to the image (and note it doesn't need a wrapper). And next time please (re)search before asking. Also, the posted markup is invalid. You should not expect it to work until fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I understand my questions is not the greatest, but I really tried a lot of things before asking here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of "col-md-value" for the Image and "col-md-(12-value)" for the text area, so it spans the `entire row (made of 12 columns)`. Since, it is responsive, for `small displays it will wrap in the next row`.

*View it on full page display*. If you want to display them side by side for even smaller viewports, you can just add the following to **row-one** class:

`display:flex`

```css
.book-box {
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#book-desc {
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  text-align: justify !important;
  text-justify: inter-word !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container book-wrapper">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="container book-box">
      <div class="row row-one">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">

          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8">

          <h2 id="book-title">Title</h2>
          <span id="book-desc">This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random ndom stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is rand stuff  </span>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

**Reponsive for even smaller screens:**

```css
.book-box {
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#book-desc {
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  text-align: justify !important;
  text-justify: inter-word !important;
}

.row-one{
display:flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container book-wrapper">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="container book-box">
      <div class="row row-one">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">

          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8">

          <h2 id="book-title">Title</h2>
          <span id="book-desc">This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random ndom stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is random stuff This is rand stuff  </span>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hi there. thanks for the answer. When I run the code snippet the output looks like the one I currently have. I am looking to display the text in the right